# Resizing image for XXHDPI

Tags: android, hdpi

I have an image that is being displayed perfectly for MDPI. 
Its resolution is `191 x 255.`

Then I resize it to XXDPI, using 1:3 proportion, it gets to `573 x 765`.
Still, when the emulator displays it, the quality is not as good as the MDPI one. 
It gets clearly poor.

For both cases, I am using it `Wrap Content`

If I display both images on a image editor, they have perfect quality.
Why does that happen? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Well, your monitor has a far lower density than that, and so the emulator has to fake the density. Measuring image quality on an emulator is nearly pointless IMHO. You are going to need to test that on hardware.

Comment: So it means it can actually be displayed with good quality on a hand/table?

Comment: `Then I resize it to XXDPI` What exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: Knowing MDPI is the baseline (1dp = 1px), and XXHDPI is 1dp = 3px, then I resize the image 3 times its current size.

Comment: You resize? If you don't have a higher resolution BITMAP image you can't just magically add fidelity to it by resizing it in mspaint. If you don't provide xxhdpi drawables android will scale mdpi or whatever is available automatically. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Eugen  I am not sure if this is the right way to do it.
I understand Android picks up the correct drawable for each situation.. but are not we supposed to insert an image version for each drawable-dpi folder?

Comment: Yes we are but obviously if we don't have the imagery in higher resolution to begin with plain resize in mspaint isn't going to magically make it sharper. If you have a vector image, you could generate appropriate sizes beforehand and put them in respective dpi directories. If you have a special upscaling/downscaling algorithm you could scale up/down beforehand... But if you just have an image and have no way of making it more precise, then you're just wasting space on the device.

Comment: I create the images for my app in high resolution (usually 2000px x 2000px) then I use Reshade application to resize it without losing much quality. It seems to work fine so far.
Do you suggest me another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metrics);
int widthPixels = metrics.widthPixels;
int heightPixels = metrics.heightPixels;
float widthDpi = metrics.xdpi;
float heightDpi = metrics.ydpi;
float widthInches = widthPixels / widthDpi;
float heightInches = heightPixels / heightDpi;
double diagonalInches = Math.sqrt((widthInches * widthInches) + (heightInches * heightInches)); // this code returns the actual screen size (eg. 7,8,9,10 inches in double format ex: 7.932189832)
diagonalInches = (double) Math.round(diagonalInches * 10) / 10; // round up to first decimal places

ArrayList<Integer> imageId = new ArrayList<>();
imageId.clear();

for (Integer i : imageNum){ // uses loop since im using TransitionDrawable to change images in single view
    String stringID;
    if (isPortrait) {
        stringID = "featured_img_" + i.toString() + "_port"; // portrait images
    } else {
        if (diagonalInches >= 7 && diagonalInches <=8){
            stringID = "featured_img_" + i.toString() + "_land_b"; // landscape images this is the drawable filename
        } else {
            stringID = "featured_img_" + i.toString() + "_land_a"; //landscape images this is the drawable filename
        }
    }
    int drawableId = getResId(stringID);
    imageId.add(drawableId); // adding it to arraylist
}
```

Comment: @RashidCordero Do you mind adding some comments in the code and describing what this code does? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can add android:scaleType=" . . . " on what you want for your image to be displayed

Comment: Did not quite understand.. I use scaleType for resizing, or centering images.. How would this help in my case?

Comment: using scaletype will help you get what you want your imageview to look like. for example you use fitXY then it will fit your image in its container. In your case you use WRAP_CONTENT which will wrap the content size.

Comment: I think your problem is that your app not choosing the right resource folder of your imageview

Comment: I thought about your latter comment. But since I created all folders correctly, why would that happen?

I used:

drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-hdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi

Comment: it sometimes happen to me, so i just pick image on background instead of letting it pick the image on the folder

Comment: in my case i had a project for tablet. i made images good for xxhdpi and xhdpi but it doesnt pick the right image for me. so i just get the device screensize and select the image on it. i will post the code on new answer.